# Two Excel files. How to match words in one file to the sentence in the other using python script

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have two excel files

file 1 contains names of different brands ----eg:Audi,BMW,Snickers,Puma,etc

file 2 contains those brand's product description/some random sentences

---eg: Audi mainly promotes through sponsorship with automobile races and brands, TV shows, video games and movies.

Jackson drove a Porsche 911 turbo,etc

the task is to check whether the brand names of file 1 is there on any sentence of file 2 .if yes then create a new csv file with 2 columns 1)Brand name 2)Respective product description

Wherever the product name has no brands, print “No Brand Found”.

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
dfA = pd.read_excel('product name.xlsx')  
dfB = pd.read_excel('brands.xlsx')  

b=[]
for brand in dfB["Brands"]:
    b.append([brand.lower()])


result=[]

for sentence in dfA['Product Name']:
    sentences = sentence.lower()    
    for word in sentences.split():
        if word in b:
             result.append([word,sentences])

with open("final.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow(["Brand","Product Name"])
        writer.writerows(result)


f.close()
```

But I'm missing something here because I'm getting an empty final.csv file.

I hope you got my point also I am a novice in coding

Answer (score 1):

Your `b` variable is an array of 1-item arrays.
You need to remove square brackets from the append statement:

```
b.append(brand.lower())
```

Printing things out is a good debugging technique that let you ensure that everything is exactly as it was intended.

Comment: @tress I've updated my answer based on the new information.